# ¿Es posible efectuar un salto de página según algunas condiciones en R markdown?

Tags: r, tablas, r-markdown

Quisiera generar un documento con **R markdown** que hiciera una especie de **salto de página inteligente**. Me explico:

Quiero que mi documento inicie una tabla en una nueva página cuando esta tabla se tenga que generar en hojas diferentes, ya que visualmente no es práctico. Es decir, que si la tabla generada ha de **partirse porque no cabe en una hoja**, que esta tabla se genere en una nueva página automáticamente. Actualmente tengo que generar el documento en word, anotar aquellas tablas que quedan entre una hoja y otra, para posteriormente añadir los `\newpage` donde correspondan, entonces cada vez que modifico mínimamente el documento tengo que reubicar los `\newpage` y dedicarle demasiado tiempo.

Comment: A que salida apuntas ¿PDF o Word?

Comment: Word, ya que no creo que tenga los conocimientos necesarios para generar el documento tal y como deseo desde R markdown y tenga que modificarlo desde Microsoft Word.

Comment: Y que usas para mostrar las tablas? kable, flextable, pander, gt, etc

Comment: Por ahora, simplemente con la librería printr estoy obteniendo resultados satisfactorios aunque creo que posiblemente más adelante necesite alguna de las opciones que mencionas. Lo que no me esperaba es que la respuesta a mi pregunta varíe en función del paquete que esté empleando para hacer las tablas.

Comment: Con flextable supuestamente se puede utilizando el comando `ft.split = FALSE` en la cabecera del chunk donde está la tabla. Hasta el momento a mi no me ha funcionado, pero quizás a ti sí

Comment: Hola Juan, el problema básico es que para saber dónde debería ir un salto de página, hay que generar el documento en una primer "pasada" y luego interpretarlo y saber dónde colocar este salto. Esto obviamente no lo resuelve Knitr y sería muy complejo también que lo haga. El Latex/Pdf, hay una forma de resolverlo usando objetos "flotantes": https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions, aquí también hay un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984596/prevent-table-being-split-in-rmarkdown

Comment: En Word, es un poco más difícil, la idea, aunque no he podido investigarla, es poder "modificar" los estilos de las tablas con las que se generan desde R, puedes crear un documento en blanco y configurara los estilos para usarlo luego como template e incluirlo en la generación. Lo he hecho alguna vez para modificar tipos de letras y otras cosas, habría que probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

¡Si es posible! Al ser un enlace con el software de gestión documental LaTex une los dos lenguajes

Utiliza

\newpage <- Nueva página (Page Break)